# Displaying multilevel subcategory

Tags: menu, submenu

I'm using the following code to display the subcategory of specific categories in a hardcoded mega menu:

```
<?php
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3);
foreach ($children as $category):
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
    echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
endforeach;?>
```

This works great, but some of these subcategories has subcategories of their own, and I would like to display those too. How do I modify the above to include another level?

Comment: Try referring to this blog : 
**http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading each category individually is a lot slower then loading all at once.
It's better to load all, and then just pick the ones you need.

So lets assume you have a loaded base category and want to iterate over all children recursively

```
$baseCategory->load(3);
```

Fetch all children, regardless of depth:

```
$allChildren = $baseCategory->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like' => $baseCategory->getPath() . '/%'));
// Put some addAttributeToSelect() here if needed
```

Then, loop over all children:

```
$children = $allChildren->getItemsByColumnValue('parent_id', $baseCategory->getId());
foreach ($children as $child) {
    // Do whatever you want to do here
    // Then go one level deeper:
    $secondLevelChildren = $allChildren->getItemsByColumnValue('parent_id', $child->getId());
    foreach ($secondLevelChildren as $child2) {
        // .. and so on
    }
}
```

If you want to simply recurse to the bottom, use a recursive function instead of nested loops.